# Replacing Dell touchpad drivers with Synaptic ones

Tags: drivers, touchpad, acer-aspire, dell-latitude

I was temporarily using a budget Acer laptop for a while since my preferred Dell laptop had some h/w issues. Now that I got it back working I realized the touchpad driver on the cheap Acer was implemented much more to my liking in several aspects.

The Dell driver comes with a separate "Dell branded" settings application whereas on the Acer all settings are embedded in Windows touchpad settings. On the Acer you can customize all basic multi-finger gestures quite freely, smooth scrolling works perfectly on Windows explorer and Chrome etc. while the Dell lacks on all those aspects and has some additional features I simply hate.

So, I'd obviously prefer to have similar functionality as the Acer on the Dell which in turn has much nicer hardware. I believe I still have the Acer setup file on the Acer, any advice before I try installing it on the Dell?

Both laptops are running Windows 10

**Acer Aspire ES1-433-33KZ** (Synaptics touchpad)
 Hardware ids:
 HID\VEN_SYNA&DEV_7DAB&Col04
 HID\SYNA7DAB&Col04
 HID*SYNA7DAB&Col04
 HID\VID_06CB&UP:FF00_U:0001
 HID_DEVICE_UP:FF00_U:0001
 HID_DEVICE_UPR:FF00-FFFF
 HID_DEVICE

**Dell Latitude E5550** (Alps Alpine OEM touchpad)
 Hardware ids:
 ACPI\VEN_DLL&DEV_062C
 ACPI\DLL062C
 *DLL062C

Comment: What you want is not possible the two devices are incompatible with one another, you can’t just install the driver for one touchpad and expect it to work with a completely different touchpad. Windows won’t recognize the driver even supports the device anyway. The driver is only a portion of that behavior anyway, the actual hardware, must also support the gestures. I don’t actually know what your question is, since what I believe your asking, is (to me) very clearly not possible

Comment: Thanks for your input! I see what you mean but I've sometimes had luck with other suppliers' drivers when trying to get an old laptop to work with newer versions of Windows. I admit knowing very little about touchpads but I'd still think that there wouldn't be so many ways to implement one.
For instance in my experience all laptop webcams use USB so I'd say that there is a good chance that both touchpads are using the same communication bus as well (especially as both laptops are about the same age). From there, I don't think the idea is quite as preposterous and I AM going to try it :)

Comment: You won't be able to modify an .inf file, to allow an unsupported touchpad, use a driver designed to work with a different touchpad.

Comment: To see if the Dell touchpad settings can be changed without the proprietary Dell drivers, try running Windows (or Linux) from USB first, and see how that works, *before* making changes to the system that might leave the touchpad inoperative. Creating a live Ubuntu USB is trivial, and Hasleo has a WinToUSB builder. In either case, the Dell drivers would *not* be installed.